# Is there an easy way to completely customize Django Admin Site to display variables that are not fields?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

I realize I can overwrite the templates, and I have in the past to alter the Add model form, and the Change model form.  However, I found that overwriting the templates was a little confusing and very hard to completely customize.  My issue is that I want to display (with an editable text box) variables that are not fields, and I am having a difficult time figuring out how to do this. Because Django model fields cannot be lists (I know you can make it into a string, and then parse it like a list), but basically I want to store all of my information in one field (because it is all related and doesnt make my already long model even longer), but then display them on the admin site as separate fields.  Is this possible or is there an easy way to do this without completely overwriting the template code?  Also, it definitely constrains my model as I queried the max amount of fields for the variable I want to store. So I have 8 fields just in case, but the majority of my models only use 2 or 3 of the fields, and since I dont know how many fields are going to be used, Id like it to be dynamic.  So for instance.

My model would be like this:

models.py

```
class MyModel(Model.model):
    field1 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    field2 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    field3 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    field4 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    field5 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    field6 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    field7 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    field8 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And ideally I would want to store all of the information in one field as string that acts like a list when I parse through it.

```
class MyModel(Model.model):
    field = models.FloatField(null=True, blank = True)`
```

But, I want to display on my admin site 8 boxes from only one field. Is this possible without a major reconstruction of the template code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin pages are just an app in the django source code like any other app you could write.  So in that sense, it can be completely customized.  I'd recommend you take a look at the source code in

```
<wherever you keep django>/django/contrib/admin
```

and see how it's currently implemented, and you can c/p any of that code and modify it however you want.

But is there an easy way to completely customize it the way you're looking for without major reconstruction?  I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks!  I really appreciate your response.  And shoot, that is what I was afraid of.  I have looked in there before to modify my AddForm and Change Form Forms based on how they had it set up for the User Forms, so I will look into the source code more closely!

Comment: No problem!  Yeah it's too bad, but I think time you spend reading the source code isn't really lost time--you learn a lot about the best ways to do things in django

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I think your right.  Upon my initial dive into the source code, it was a bit confusing, but it definitely helped me change my forms.  This will be a little more in depth, but I will learn more!

Comment: Also it'd be awesome if you'd accept this answer :)

Comment: Yep I already did!  Does it show up for you as accepted?  I cannot publicly  affect displayed posts yet as I do not post very often.